# Zend Framework: Select duplicate rows

Tags: php, zend-framework

That is my table:

```
mat_id| yes| no | type
  1   | 1  | 0  |  3
  1   | 1  | 0  |  3
  2   | 1  | 1  |  3
  3   | 1  | 0  |  3
```

My select query:

```
$q = $db->select()->from('tableName', 'mat_id')->where('type = ?', 3)->group('yes')->having('COUNT(yes) > 1');
```

But why select `mat_id = 1` only, should take `mat_id =1,3` ?

Comment: I cont get you.Do you mean You want to select another column..??

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is not understandable. You need to make clear what you want us to help with. What is your current result and what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$db->select()->->distinct()->from('tableName', 'mat_id')->where('type = ?', 3)->group('yes')->having('COUNT(yes) > 1');
```

Comment: Again select only `mat_id = 1`

Comment: you are saying to display only mat_id =1,3.For this your condition should be where('type = ? AND no = ?', array(3,0)).Thus query should be $db->select()->->distinct()->from('tableName', 'mat_id')->where('type = ? AND no = ?', array(3,0))->group(array('yes','mat_id'))->having('COUNT(yes) > 1');

Comment: I don't know why but again select only mat_id = 1